# Merge multiple int columns/rows into one numpy array (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with few columns and rows. I want to merge the columns into one and then merge the rows based on `id` and `date` into one.

Currently I am doing so by:

```
df['matrix'] = df[[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20,col21,col22,col23,col24,col25,col26,col27,col28,col29,col30,col31,col32,col33,col34,col35,col36,col37,col38,col39,col40,col41,col42,col43,col44,col45,col46,col47,col48]].values.tolist()
df = df.groupby(['id','date'])['matrix'].apply(list).reset_index(name='matrix')
```

This gives me the matrix in form of a `list`.
Later I convert it into `numpy.ndarray` using:

```
df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].apply(np.array)
```

This is a small segment of my dataset for reference:

```
id,date,col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20,col21,col22,col23,col24,col25,col26,col27,col28,col29,col30,col31,col32,col33,col34,col35,col36,col37,col38,col39,col40,col41,col42,col43,col44,col45,col46,col47,col48
16,2014-06-22,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
16,2014-06-22,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
16,2014-06-22,2,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
16,2014-06-22,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0
16,2014-06-22,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,0
```

Though the above piece of code works fine for small datasets, but sometimes crashes for larger ones. Specifically `df['matrix'].apply(np.array)` statement.

Is there a way by which I can perform the merging to fetch me a `numpy.array`? This would save a lot of time.

Comment: You wind up having 2 `Series.apply`. You might cut down on everything with just `df[[f'col{i}'for i in range(0,48)]].groupby([df.id, df.date]).apply(np.array)`

Comment: @ALollz `df['matrix'].apply(np.array)` statement crashes the system. Therefore I want a substitute for it. Using this even in for loop won't help much.

Anyway I would try this as well.

Comment: @ALollz kindly verify the syntax of the code statement, it is giving me errors

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: @ALollz Python 3.6.7

Answer (score 0):

No need to merge the columns at first. Split DataFrame using **groupby** and then flatten the result

```
matrix=df.set_index(['id','date']).groupby(['id','date']).apply(lambda x: x.values.flatten())
```